# Find all possible paths in a graph using Matlab Brute Force Search

Tags: matlab, graph, brute-force, search-path

I need to find all paths with a graph, and save these paths. My starting nodes are A, B or C, and the final node is G. My graphs have maximum 16 unweighted vertices.

I made the Matlab code below, but this has problems with *bifurcations*. Also, I don't know how to impose the starting and the final nodes. Can anyone help me with this?

```
path       = cell(1,10) ;  % initialize
% one_graph  ={'AH','BO','CN','EG','EN','EO','HO','KN'} % (Graph example)
one_graph  ={'AH','BN','DH','DN','GN'} % (Graph example)

for p = 1:length(one_graph)

edge  = one_graph(p);
% In each graph there is only 1:1 conections
% detect node 1
existing_node1 = edge{1}(1) ;
Index_existing_node1 = strfind(allnodes, existing_node1) ;
[row1,col1] = find(ismember(allnodes, existing_node1));
 % detect node 2
existing_node2 = edge{1}(2) ;
Index_existing_node2 = strfind(allnodes, existing_node2);
[row2,col2] = find(ismember(allnodes, existing_node2));

path_nonz = path(~cellfun('isempty',path))   ;
t         = length(path_nonz)                ;
if t>0  % save the first 2 nodes in the path
ttt = strcmp(allnodes(row1), path{t});
ttt2 = strcmp(allnodes(row2), path{t});       
end;
if t==0
    path{t+1} = allnodes{row1}  ; 
    path{t+2} = allnodes{row2}  ;
elseif ttt == 1
    % disp('connect right')
    path{t+1} = allnodes{row2}  ;
elseif ttt2 == 1
    % disp('connect right')
    path{t+1} = allnodes{row1}  ;
else 
    disp('Not next vertex') 
end
end
```

For example, for

```
one_graph  ={'AH','BN','DH','DN','GN'} % (Graph example)
```

I should save the following paths:

path1 = **A**HDN**G**

path2 = **B**N**G**

and for

```
one_graph  ={'AH','BO','CN','EG','EN','EO','HO','KN'} % (Graph example)
```

I should save the following paths:

path1 = **A**HOE**G**

path2 = **B**OE**G**

path3 = **C**NE**G**

**UPDATE 1:**

From the adjacency matrix `B(:,:,1)`

```
B =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I derive the proper adjacency list:

```
Asparse = sparse(B(:,:,1));
Asparse =

 (8,1)        1
(14,2)        1
 (8,4)        1
(14,4)        1
(14,7)        1
 (1,8)        1
 (4,8)        1
 (2,14)       1
 (4,14)       1
 (7,14)       1
```

Then, I tried to use the BFS algorithm found on [Matlab Website](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24134-gaimc---graph-algorithms-in-matlab-code/content/gaimc/bfs.m)

```
 [distances,times,pred] = bfs(Asparse,1);
```

But, this doesn't save the paths. It just saves the previous node of each current node (in `pred`) and the distance from the initial node to each node (in `distances`). Any idea, how to save each path?

Comment: Generally, finding all paths in a graph is done using Depth-First Search. I would start by converting your graph into a proper adjacency list. To allow paths to start with a subset of vertices, say `{A, B, C}`, you would push those to the stack as the first step of your DFS, probably in reverse order to make the path ordering more logical. To make sure that you don't continue on a path once you've reached your endpoint `G`, make the adjacency list of `G` empty. Once you've found all of the possible paths, eliminate those that don't end at `G`, if any.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have constructed the adjacency matrix. I will make also the adjacency list and try to implement DFS.

Comment: @beaker Since I'm not very good with programming, I'm trying to use an already implemented version of BFS. Can you suggest a way to save the all the paths?

Comment: I'll write an answer some code that should recover the path. Note that the function you're using 1) is BFS, not DFS (might not matter) and 2) only finds the first path to each node from the starting point. More in a minute...

Comment: I checked DFS and although it might be faster then BFS, I don't agree with the search manner. It has some jumps that I find hard to follow. And it doesn't verify all nodes. I observed that it only find one path.. I am searching for all.

Comment: That's going to be a problem because it looks as though your BFS is going to find only one path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72189/discussion-between-user2061773-and-beaker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to write a custom function to do this since 1) most BFS/DFS functions stop when the goal is reached and 2) they explicitly ignore cycles, which are required for multiple paths to the same target.

I believe this will get you what you need. I've made a slight modification to the adjacency matrix in your example to create an edge from `{2,7}` and `{7,2}` so that there would be two paths from `2` to `14`. Note that this is a recursive function, so if you get around 500 nodes or so you're going to have problems and we'll have to come up with a version that uses an explicit stack.

```
function paths = findpaths(Adj, nodes, currentPath, start, target)
   paths = {};
   nodes(start) = 0;
   currentPath = [currentPath start];
   childAdj = Adj(start,:) & nodes;
   childList = find(childAdj);
   childCount = numel(childList);
   if childCount == 0 || start == target
      if start == target
         paths = [paths; currentPath];
      end
      return;
   end
   for idx = 1:childCount
      currentNode = childList(idx);
      newNodes = nodes;
      newNodes(currentNode) = 0;
      newPaths = findpaths(Adj, newNodes, currentPath, currentNode, target);
      paths = [paths; newPaths];
   end
end
```

If you call this function like this:

```
A =[
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1; 
 1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
 0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0];

unusedNodes=ones(1,size(A,1));
start=2;
target=14;
emptyPath=[];

allPaths = findpaths(A, unusedNodes, emptyPath, start, target)
```

the output should be:

```
allPaths =
{
  [1,1] =

      2    7   14

  [2,1] =

      2   14

}
```

Naturally, you need to call this for each starting node.

---

Actually, you don't have to call this multiple times. There was one more tip I forgot to tell you. If your graph has `n` nodes and you introduce a new node `n+1` that has edges only to your candidate start nodes, you can call the function once with the new node as the start.

So if I add node `15` to the graph above with edges:

```
{15,1}, {15,2} 
%// I wouldn't bother with {1,15} and {2,15}, they're totally unnecessary
```

and call the function with `start = 15`, here's what I get:

```
allPaths = 
{
  [1,1] =

     15    1    8    4   14

  [2,1] =

     15    2    7   14

  [3,1] =

     15    2   14

}
```

You now have all of the paths with one call, although you need to remove the new node `15` from the head of each path.

Comment: But I need to improve somehow the BFS to get all paths, right? What if there're two paths from node 1 to the goal node? My goal node is 7, and the possible starting ones are 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked. Printing out the return value from the function should also work. (That's where I got my output.)

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much! You are a great person. :) I had to modify `if start == target, paths{end+1,1} = currentPath; end` at lines 10 and 19 of your function. Because with curved brackets it does not work. It gives this error: `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch`. Now, of course, I get a cell into a cell into a cell.. :) Any idea how to solve it? Does it run as it is for you? @beaker

Comment: @Aquila It worked for me, but I ran it in Octave. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: I will find a way to solve it, don't worry. Did I say your function is great? :) Thanks again!

Comment: Try this: `paths=[paths; currentPath];`

Comment: Should I initiate with `paths = [];`? If  I do that, then it finds one path (I can see it from`paths=[paths; currentPath]`), but it returns `allPaths=1`. Moreover, the algorithms stops. Should I put `paths=[paths; currentPath]` online at line 10? I put it also at line 19.

Comment: @Aquila We can talk on the chat room you set up earlier, if you like.